# How to render Android native google map in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, native, google-maps-android-api-2

We are not able to add ground overlay on top of Google Maps using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter), since they are not exposing the method to add ground overlay.

So we tried to load it as native google maps and add the ground overlay, then render this view as Android PlatformView in flutter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are packages on pub.dev to help with displaying maps in flutter applications. Some of these packages include [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) as well as [map_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/map_launcher). These are very popular packages that can help you use map functionality in your app.

**Note:** In order to use google maps, you will need to create an account with google maps.

Hope you find this useful